# Default group in Springdoc

Tags: springdoc

Is there a way to group all ungrouped controller api's to a single default group instead of specifically defining a `GroupedOpenApi` bean with exclusion?
For eg, if I have a controller

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping(value="/user")
    public String test() {
         return "user";
    }
    @GetMapping(value="/pet")
    public String test1() {
         return "pet";
    }
}
```

and a `GroupedOpenApi` bean for `/user`

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi userGroup() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("user").pathsToMatch("/user").build();
}
```

This one generates openapi json for the url `/v3/api-docs/user` properly. Now I want the other `/pet` api to be available in a default group without adding another `GroupedOpenApi` bean specifically for `/pet`. So is there a way to generate a default group out of the box which will have all the ungrouped apis which are not filtered with any `GroupedOpenApi` bean? Or adding another `GroupedOpenApi` bean with exclude patterns is only solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wondered about the same, but I didn't find any mention to a default group in the documentation.

So I browsed the internal code of springdoc and I found a constant

```
 public static final String DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME = "springdocDefault";
```

but it's used by SpringDoc only when we instruct it to expose the actuator endpoints

```
 springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

Look at the class `SpringdocActuatorBeanFactoryConfigurer`, Springdoc creates a dedicated group for the actuator endpoints and it does care to group all other endpoints in that `springdocDefault`.

That constant is not used in any part of the library. IMO, apart from the actuator feature, once a group is created, it's up to the developer to group the other endpoints in another group. It looks like is not an out-of-the-box feature.

Thus, I think if you don't want to group explicitely the endpoint `pet`, your second question is the solution

```
GroupedOpenApi.builder().group(DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME).pathsToExclude("/user")
```